# changing default download location in chrome using Pytest_mozwebqa

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please help how do i change the chrome settings in selenium using pytest to download files to a desired location.
what should i add to the below command in run configurations of eclipse to change the download path

--baseurl='http://example.com'--driver=chrome

Answer (score 2):

In Python itself, it would be:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": "some/path", "download.directory_upgrade": true})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the/path/to/the/driver.exe", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Related: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=330

If I understand correctly how this "Pytest_mozwebqa" thingy works, you could try adding this command line:

```
--chromeopts='{"prefs":{"download.default_directory":"some/path","download.directory_upgrade":true}}'
```

Comment: Thanks Cherry but if i use the above command line,i am getting the error:   **platform win32 -- Python 2.7.9 -- pytest-2.4.1
ERROR: file not found: c:/ler,plugins: mozwebqa, xdist .**                 This is how i have written the command **--baseurl=http://example.com --chromeopts='{"prefs":{"download.default_directory": "c:/ler", "download.directory_upgrade": true}}' --driver=chrome -k test_nid_config_manage"**   .please help

Comment: Try removing the spaces in the `chromeopts` argument and try using `c:\\ler` instead of `c:/ler`

Comment: I tried as u said cherry but now its giving me value error. **"ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"**

Comment: Depending on your shell you might even need 4 backslashes instead of 2. If it still doesn't work, try going back to the forward slash you initially had (but still without the spaces)

Comment: Are you still getting errors, or is it just not working for you? (Runs but still downloads in old folder)

Comment: I am still getting the same error : No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Try removing the single quotes I added, so it's just `--chromeopts={...}` (although this is how they do it in the [docs](https://github.com/Impactstory/pytest-impactstory/blob/master/README.md#setting-google-chrome-options)). Which shell are you using? CMD? PowerShell? Bash?

Comment: Bash is used in my project.i tried removing the single quotes too.still same error :(

Comment: For bash I think it should work when you add the single quotes around the whole string, i.e. `'--chromeopts={...}'`. Then you also need only one backslash (`c:\ler`).

Comment: A google search brought me here and this helped me sort out my VBA code! I used `Driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "\my\dir"` and it downloaded just fine! The key for me was the `"download.` in front of `default_directory`. Thanks @CherryDT